# How can i make routing detect a subroute with routeprefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API action method like this

```
[HttpPost] 
[Route("{idFlux}/Transfert")] 
public IHttpActionResult Post(int idFlux, Transfert parametre)
```

The controller has a prefix of

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/Flux")]
```

`localhost/api/v1/Flux/59` works, but `localhost/api/v1/Flux/59/Transfert` is not working, and I think everything is set right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add both acceptable routes to action

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{idFlux}/Transfert")]
[Route("{idFlux}")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(int idFlux, Transfert parametre)
```

Comment: The thing is there is a difference between the localhost/api/v1/Flux/ which posts a Flux object, and localhost/api/v1/Flux/59/Transfert which posts a transfer for the Flux with id 59, is it still valid?

Comment: @tahtoh If you have separate action for `localhost/api/v1/Flux/` then evertyhing will work fine

Comment: the thing is logically i dont want to accept this as a route to posting a transfer, [Route("{idFlux}")] @Alexander , even adding that just results in Erreur HTTP 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: @tahtoh So what is your original question about? Cause now I'm confused what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Just that when i try to add a subroute on the main route to post get info on that ressource it just doesnt work with route attributes, routes attributes work for me on the main branch only aka Flux

Comment: when i do this as a route [Route("api/v1/Flux/{idFlux}/Transfert")] i get the action to be hit, but if i do [Route("{idFlux}/Transfert")] it doesn't

Comment: @tahtoh Please add more code samples of what you have and what you are trying to achieve, cause it works fine for me

Comment: it actually works when i started over from ground up... i'll give you a thumb up and delete question for your efforts